# Swift 3 optional parameters

Tags: swift, swift3

Is it possible to create optional initialization parameters in Swift so I can create an object from JSON with the values returned from the API call, but then when I'm saving that object later I can also save the downloaded UIImage for one of the urls I got before.

Example:

```
  class Story: NSObject, NSCoding {
        var id: Int?
        var title, coverImageURL: String?
        var coverImage: UIImage?

    required init?(anId: Int?, aTitle: String?, aCoverImageURL: String?) {
            self.id = anId
            self.title = aTitle
            self.coverImageURL = aCoverImageURL
    }
    convenience init?(json: [String: Any]) {
            let id = json["id"] as? Int
            let title = json["title"] as? String
            let coverImageURL = json["cover_image"] as? String

            self.init(
                anId: id,
                aTitle: title,
                aCoverImageURL: coverImageURL,
            )
      }
```

Then Later I want to save objects to memory

```
    //MARK: Types
    struct PropertyKey {
        static let id = "id"
        static let title = "title"
        static let coverImageURL = "coverImageURL"
        static let coverImage = "coverImage"
    }

    //MARK: NSCoding
    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encode(id, forKey: PropertyKey.id)
        aCoder.encode(title, forKey: PropertyKey.title)
        aCoder.encode(coverImageURL, forKey: PropertyKey.coverImageURL)
        aCoder.encode(coverImage, forKey: PropertyKey.coverImage)
    }

    required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        guard let id = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: PropertyKey.id) as? Int else {
            os_log("Unable to decode the id for a Story object.", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug)
            return nil
        }
        guard let title = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: PropertyKey.title) as? String else {
            os_log("Unable to decode the title for a Story object.", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug)
            return nil
        }

        let coverImageURL = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: PropertyKey.coverImageURL) as? String
        let coverImage = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: PropertyKey.coverImage) as? UIImage

        self.init(
            anId: id,
            aTitle: title,
            aCoverImageURL: coverImageURL,
            coverImage: coverImage,
        )
    }
```

Does this make sense? I want to be able to save a Story object as soon as I get the response from the API, but later when I save the story to memory, I want to be able to save the fetched UIImage for the coverImage.

How would I do that?

Comment: So only coverImage should be optional

Comment: BTW you need to convert your UIImage to Data to be able to save it to disk (encode)

Comment: @LeoDabus correct.

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea to add the image to your class. Better to just add a property for its local fileURL once you finish downloading it. remoteURL and localURL.

Comment: Why don't you just create a struct instead of a class and if you need it to persist just save it as a json string using the same format it comes from your server

Comment: That's a good idea! So I save either the local URL or the remote URL to the same field?

Comment: You can keep the remote also. It might be useful if you don't want to download it twice to have a reference

Comment: try something like this `struct Story {
    let id: Int
    let title: String
    let remote: String
    var local: String
    init?(json: [String: Any]) {
        self.id = json["id"] as? Int ?? 0
        self.title = json["title"] as? String ?? ""
        self.remote = json["coverImageURL"] as? String ?? ""
        self.local = ""
    }
    var json: String {
        guard let data = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: ["id": id, "title": title, "coverImageURL": remote]) else { return "" }
        return String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) ?? ""
    }
}`

Comment: `let story = Story(json: ["id":1,"title": "Title 1","coverImageURL":"http://www.example.com/image.jpg"])

story?.json  // "{"id":1,"title":"Title 1","coverImageURL":"http://www.example.com/image.jpg"}"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why no one took the easy points on this answer, but the answer is to simply make your properties optionals, and then you can set them with a value, or nil. You can also create convenience initializers that automatically set certain values to nil if you want. So, using my app as an example, I have a model that gets built from an API call. that model has values like `id`, `created_at`, etc that don't exist until a record is saved to the server, but I create objects locally, store them, and eventually send them to the server, so I need to be able to set the above values only when creating an object from JSON, so here is what I did:

```
class Story: NSObject, NSCoding {
        var id: Int?
        var title, coverImageURL: String?
        var coverImage: UIImage?

    required init?(anId: Int?, aTitle: String?, aCoverImageURL: String?) {
            self.id = anId
            self.title = aTitle
            self.coverImageURL = aCoverImageURL
    }
    convenience init?(json: [String: Any]) {
            let id = json["id"] as? Int
            let title = json["title"] as? String
            let coverImageURL = json["cover_image"] as? String

            self.init(
                anId: id,
                aTitle: title,
                aCoverImageURL: coverImageURL,
            )
      }

      convenience init?(aTitle: String, aCoverImage: UIImage?) {
            let title = aTitle
            let subtitle = aSubtitle
            let coverImage = aCoverImage
            let isActive = activeStatus

            self.init(
                anId: nil,
                aTitle: title,
                aCoverImageURL: nil,
                aCoverImage: coverImage,
            )
        }
```

As you can see, I only set two of the values when I'm creating an object locally, and the other values are just set to `nil`. To allow a value to be set to `nil`, just make it an optional when setting it. Simple!